# Generate week start date, week end date, month week no by using the given date range in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have given a date range as input ie a start date and an end date, I need to construct an array that contains the week No and the week start date, and the week end date as output.

Input:

```
startDate = "2022-10-21"
endDate = "2022-12-05"
```

Output:

```
result = [{
weekNo: "Oct 2022 - Week 4",
weekStartDate: "2022-10-21",
weekEndDate: "2022-10-23"
},
{
weekNo: "Oct 2022 - Week 5",
weekStartDate: "2022-10-24",
weekEndDate: "2022-10-30"
},
{
weekNo: "Oct 2022 - Week 6",
weekStartDate: "2022-10-31",
weekEndDate: "2022-10-31"
},
{
weekNo: "Nov 2022 - Week 1",
weekStartDate: "2022-11-01",
weekEndDate: "2022-11-06"
},
{
weekNo: "Nov 2022 - Week 2",
weekStartDate: "2022-11-07",
weekEndDate: "2022-11-13"
},
{
weekNo: "Nov 2022 - Week 3",
weekStartDate: "2022-11-14",
weekEndDate: "2022-11-20"
},
{
weekNo: "Nov 2022 - Week 4",
weekStartDate: "2022-11-21",
weekEndDate: "2022-11-27"
},
{
weekNo: "Nov 2022 - Week 5",
weekStartDate: "2022-11-28",
weekEndDate: "2022-11-30"
},
{
weekNo: "Dec 2022 - Week 1",
weekStartDate: "2022-12-01",
weekEndDate: "2022-12-04"
},
{
weekNo: "Dec 2022 - Week 2",
weekStartDate: "2022-12-05",
weekEndDate: "2022-12-05"
}];
```

Based on the start date and end date I need to construct a monthly calendar week no, monthly calendar start date and end date.

My Code:

```
constructWeekDataForCustomDates(startDate, endDate) {
      let currentDay = moment(startDate).day(), addDays, weekArrayData = [];

      if (currentDay == 0) {
        addDays = 1;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 1) {
        addDays = 0;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 2) {
        addDays = 6;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 3) {
        addDays = 5;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 4) {
        addDays = 4;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 5) {
        addDays = 3;
      }
      else if (currentDay == 6) {
        addDays = 2;
      }

      while(startDate <= endDate){
        weekArrayData.push({
          checkboxName: this.getweekNoOfMonth(startDate),
          checkboxStartValue: moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          checkboxEndValue: moment(startDate).add(addDays, 'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        });

        startDate = moment(startDate).add(addDays, 'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        addDays =  6;
      }
      console.log(weekArrayData)
    }
 // Function To get week no based on the date
 getweekNoOfMonth (date) {
    let input = moment(date)
    const firstDayOfMonth = input.clone().startOf('month');
    const firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfMonth.clone().startOf('week');
  
    const offset = firstDayOfMonth.diff(firstDayOfWeek, 'days');
  
    return Math.ceil((input.date() + offset) / 7);
  }
```

In my code I am getting wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try. A few points to notice:

To negate time zone and day time effects, we must compare only the date part without the time. This is done using string comparison of yyyy-mm-dd format.

Rest of the code speaks for itself. I hope I got all the end cases right.

```js
var startDate = "2022-10-21"
var endDate = "2022-12-05"

var result = getAllWeeks(startDate, endDate);
console.log(result)

function getWeekOfMonth(date) {
  var d = new Date(date);
  var p = new Date(date);
  p.setDate(1);
  var week = 1;
  while (p < d) {
    p.setDate(p.getDate() + 1)
    if (p.getDay() == 1) {
      week++;
    }
  }
  return week;
}

function formatDate(date) {
  return (date.toISOString()).split("T")[0];
}

function getWeekEnd(date, maxDate) {
  var p = new Date(date.getTime());
  var month = p.getMonth();
  while (p.getDay() != 0 && p.getMonth() == month && p < maxDate) {
    p.setDate(p.getDate() + 1)
  }
  if (p.getMonth() != month) {
    p.setDate(p.getDate() - 1)
  }
  p = new Date(formatDate(p))
  return p;
}

function getMonthName(date) {
  return date.toLocaleString('default', {
    month: 'short'
  });
}

function getAllWeeks(startDate, endDate) {
  var p = new Date(startDate);
  var d = new Date(endDate);

  var result = [];
  while (formatDate(p) <= formatDate(d)) {
    var weekEnd = getWeekEnd(p, d)
    var obj = {
      weekNo: getMonthName(p) + " " + p.getFullYear() + " - Week " + getWeekOfMonth(p),
      weekStartDate: formatDate(p),
      weekEndDate: formatDate(weekEnd),
    }
    result.push(obj);
    p.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, an answer with no library.

It seems weeks start on Monday and the first week of the month starts on the 1st and goes up to the first Sunday, so might contain from 1 to 7 days. Similarly the last week goes from the last Monday to the last day of the month.

```js
// Parse YYYY-MM-DD as local
function parseYMDLocal(s) {
  let [y, m, d] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(y, m-1, d);
}

// Format date as YYY-MM-DD
function formatYMD(date) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString('en-ca');
}

// Get week of month. Weeks start on Monday.
// First week starts on first of month
function getWeekOfMonth(date) {
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let monthStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth());
  let startMonday = new Date(monthStart.getFullYear(),
    monthStart.getMonth(), monthStart.getDate() - (monthStart.getDay() || 7) + 1);
//  return startMonday.toDateString()
  return Math.floor(Math.round((d - startMonday) / 8.64e7) / 7) + 1;
}

// Return start, end of week (Monday is start of week)
// Start not before start of moth, end not after end of month
function getWeekInMonth(date) {
  let weekStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - (date.getDay() || 7) + 1);
  let monthStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
  let weekEnd = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 7 - (date.getDay() || 7));
  let monthEnd = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)
  return {
    weekStart: weekStart < monthStart? monthStart : weekStart,
    weekEnd: weekEnd > monthEnd? monthEnd : weekEnd};
}

// Get weeks array per OP
function getWeeks(start, end) {
  let s = parseYMDLocal(start);
  let e = parseYMDLocal(end);
  if (e < s || isNaN(s) || isNaN(e)) return;
  let weeks = [];

  do {
    let {weekStart, weekEnd} = getWeekInMonth(s);
    weekStart = weekStart < s? s : weekStart;
    weekEnd = weekEnd > e? new Date(e) : weekEnd;
    weeks.push({
      weekNo: `${s.toLocaleString('en-au',{year:'numeric',month:'short'})} - ${getWeekOfMonth(s)}`,
      weekStartDate: formatYMD(weekStart),
      weekEndDate: formatYMD(weekEnd)
    });
    s = new Date(weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 1));
  } while (s <= e)
  return weeks;
}

// Example
let startDate = "2022-10-21";
let endDate = "2022-12-05";
console.log(getWeeks(startDate, endDate));
```